# A tool for transforming POJO to XML and JSON, based on xml-mapping is needed

Tags: java, xml, json, transformation, pojo

I need an open-source tool which can convert POJOs to XML and JSON strings.

Jersey (and probably other JAX-RS implementations) would fit these requirements if mappings could be configured through xml-files but not through annotations.

Is there anything suitable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**POJO to XML**

JAXB is the Java standard ([JSR-222](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) for converting Java objects to/from XML (I am a member of the JAXB expert group):

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/jaxb-xml-binding-standard.html

**POJO to JSON**

People have been using JAXB with [Jettison](http://jettison.codehaus.org/) to produce JSON.  This is how [Jersey](http://jettison.codehaus.org/) (JAX-RS reference implementation) converts POJOs to JSON by default.

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/04/jaxb-and-json-via-jettison.html

**XML Configuration**

If you require the ability to configure the metadata via XML, then you can use [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php), I'm the MOXy tech lead:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html

Comment: MOXy does look like a very promising candidate in XML space -- giving JAXB RI and XStream run for their money.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of suitable JSON libraries; aside from GSON that was mentioned, [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org) is an obvious choice. Typically you don't need any annotations; but even if you neded, Jackson can use so-called mix-in annotations which means associating configuration, not modifying actual POJOs. Finally, Jackson supports JAXB annotations if you must use them (for example, when using JAXB for producing XML).

And as an added bonus, there is Jackson extension module, [jackson-xml-databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-xml-databind), which can data bind POJOs to and from XML, so you can just use one library for both.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Castor?

http://www.castor.org/

Supports XML mapping -

http://www.castor.org/xml-mapping.html

From XML, you could use json-lib if you need JSON.

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/278-how-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-java/

Comment: It seems that this tool doesn't provide POJO to JSON transformation feature.

Comment: This is true, but POJO -> XML -> JSON would work with an additional library. Answer appended.

Answer (score 0):

Check out GSON for converting POJOs to JSON:

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

We've been using for a couple of years now.  Very excellent library.

For POJOs to XML, Jersey uses JAXB or you could roll your own serializer.